# Print all paths from Root to each leaf

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

For a Tree where each Node is provided with the following tuple:

(Value, LeftNode, RightNode)

How is it possible to print all value chains possible from root to each leaf?

For example:
(1,(2,(4,(7,None,None),None),(5, None, None)),(3,None,(6, None,None)))

It should represent the following tree:

[image: Example tree]

The expected result is:
[1,2,4,7]
[1,2,5]
[1,3,6]

Comment: what did you try? where are you stuck? did you try using recursion? did you try implementing either BFS or DFS?

Comment: I tried to use recursion, but it returned a list of lists like: [1,[2,[4,7]]], and for some reason the last one has two values, and only for left nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/

Here, you can simply start exploring tree with dfs and store the values as you go down in tree and maintain a vector of all values from the root to the current node. As soon as you finish processing that node, simply remove the values at current node from that vector. When we reached the leaf node, we simply append the values in vector to our answer.

Here is code implemented in cpp for your refernece:

```
/**
* Definition for a binary tree node.
* struct TreeNode {
*     int val;
*     TreeNode *left;
*     TreeNode *right;
*     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
* };
*/
class Solution {
 public:
   void solve(TreeNode* root, vector<int>&values, vector<string>&ans) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
        // leaf node
        string str = "";
        values.push_back(root->val);
        str += ::to_string(values[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i) {
            str += "->";
            str += ::to_string(values[i]);
        }
        ans.push_back(str);
        values.pop_back();
        return;
    }
    values.push_back(root->val);
    solve(root->left, values, ans);
    solve(root->right, values, ans);
    values.pop_back();
  }
 vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<int>values;
    vector<string>ans;
    solve(root,values,ans);
    return ans;
  }
};
```

Comment: This does not look like Python

Comment: I presented my idea in description. You may simply use this idea to implement it in your own language of choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more readable recursive generator:

```
def paths(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    val, *children = node
    if any(children):
        for child in children: 
            for path in paths(child):
                yield [val] + path
    else:
        yield [val]

>>> list(paths(root))
[[1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
```

This has the added benefit of working for nodes with arbitrary numbers of children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_paths(d, _c = []):
  val, _l, _r = d
  if _l is None and _r is None:
    yield [*_c, val]
  if _l is not None:
    yield from get_paths(_l, _c = _c+[val])
  if _r is not None:
    yield from get_paths(_r, _c = _c+[val])

print(list(get_paths((1,(2,(4,(7,None,None),None),(5, None, None)),(3,None,(6, None,None))))))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
```